# How to install zend framwork on Xampp version 1.7.1 in windows7 eternity

Tags: zend-framework

I have downloaded ZendFramework-1.11.11 and it has been extracted and then there is zend folder inside library folder of ZendFramework-1.11.11.And then it is copied and paste in the htdocs of xampp. My Xampp version Xampp win32 1.7.1 or Xampp win32 1.7.7
And Then what to do.To check in browser how to check,like localhost/myzendproject/test1.php
I need step by step guide.And also in test.php what to write for checking and in browser what will be URL.
I need your hand. Pls, guied me step by step
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) walks you through downloading Zend Framework, setting up the include_path in PHP, creating a ZF project, and creating a virtual host in Apache to map to your newly created Zend Framework project.

I'd start there and if you get stuck in a particular spot, we're happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Zend framework does not depend on the system where it will run. Follow the following article for the correct walk-through. It denotes every actions needed to get started.

[Installing Zend Framework On Windows](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Installing+Zend+Framework+on+Windows)